# Forbidden access to OneDrive pdf files via VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, onedrive, permission-denied

**GOAL:**
By VBA I have to download a pdf from OneDrive.

**PROBLEM:**
I am following a bunch of tutorials, but when the download has finished and I try to open the downloaded pdf file I receive this error message:

> "Adobe Reader could not open [name_file.pdf] because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

**ROUTINE:**
This the routine to download the file.

```vb
Sub DownloadFile(indirizzoOnedrive, indirizzoSalvataggio, nomeCommessa)
Dim myURL As String Dim Salvataggio As String Dim nomeFile As String Dim WinHttpReq As Object

myURL = indirizzoOnedrive

Salvataggio = indirizzoSalvataggio

nomeFile = nomeCommessa

Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False  'usr and pwd are commented because in one drive I permit access to everybody that has link, "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then

    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With oStream
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        .SaveToFile Salvataggio & "\" & nomeFile & ".pdf", 2
        .Close
    End With
    
End If

Set WinHttpReq = Nothing
Set oStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

**ANALYSIS**
I tried to open the downloaded pdf in a text editor and I saw that it contained HTML information.
Opening the file via a browser gives me this error message:

> *"Can't sign in
>
> Your browser is currently set to block cookies. To use this service, you must allow cookies.
>
> Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that communicate when you are logged in. For information on how to allow cookies, see the help of your web browser."*

[image: error_received_opening_file_by_browser]

The link I pass to the variable "myURL" works if open from a normal browser (so if I work on it outside the VBA code). Apparently therefore the denial seems to interest only VBA.

Comment: Are you sure the URL you're downloading from is in fact the url of a PDF and not a web page that redirects to one? In other words, does it end in ".pdf"?

Comment: Hi jsheeran, 
yes, I confirm you that url end with ".pdf"
Here the example of it (for security issue I just have modified on it personal information):

https://mydomain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_mydomain_it/Documents/App/Microsoft%20Forms/NCR_internal/Question%203/439_Tablet%20Nde.pdf


This link is generated by a tablet that compiles a Microsoft forms and upload the pdf file in specified folder in onedrive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the aforementioned code, I found a solution using this code:

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
                                 Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                                 ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                                 ByVal szURL As String, _
                                 ByVal szFileName As String, _
                                 ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                                 ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
                                 ) As Long

DownloadFileFromWeb driveFilename, folderPath, numero_conformita


Function DownloadFileFromWeb(strURL As String, strSavePath As String, namePDF As String) As Long

    Dim Salvataggio, myURL As String
    Dim downloadPDF As Long
    
    myURL = strURL
    
    Salvataggio = strSavePath & "\" & namePDF & ".pdf"
  
    downloadPDF = URLDownloadToFile(0, myURL, Salvataggio, 0, 0)
    
    If downloadPDF = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Pdf scaricato con successo!"
    Else
        MsgBox "ATTENZIONE: Pdf NON  scaricato!!!"
    End If
    
End Function
```

In this mode, the OneDrive download seems to work.